# Binary recursions search

Tags: java, recursion

JAVA Homework

Can someone give me some pointers on what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks.

16.Code a recursive solution for Exercise 11(f), Binary search of an array to locate the value a Key.

```
public class BinarySearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public static int BinarySearch(int[] sorted, int first, int upto, int key) {
            if (first < upto) {
                int mid = first + (upto - first) / 2;  // Compute mid point.
                if (key < sorted[mid]) {
                    return BinarySearch(sorted, first, mid, key);
                } else if (key > sorted[mid]) {
                    return BinarySearch(sorted, mid+1, upto , key);
                } else {
                    return mid;   // Found it.
                }
            }
            return -(first + 1);  // Failed to find key
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `first, mid`, you could use `first, mid-1`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're defining a method inside another method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    public static int BinarySearch(int[] sorted, int first, int upto, int key) {
```

Just move the `BinarySearch` method outside the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //content of this method
}

public static int BinarySearch(int[] sorted, int first, int upto, int key) {
    //content of this other method
}
```